# TableView Segue to new ViewController does not work twice

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, uitableview, swift2

I have a TableViewController in which selecting a row makes a network call, shows an activityIndicator, and in the completion block of the network call, stops the indicator and does a push segue.

In testing, I found that when going to the new view controller, going back, and selecting another row, it shows the activity indicator, but never stops or calls the push segue. The code for didSelect:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = false
    self.searchController?.active = false
    self.idx = indexPath
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.accessoryView = self.activityIndicator
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()

    self.networkingEngine?.getObjectById("\(objectId)", completion: { (object) -> Void in
        if object != nil {
            self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = true
            self.chosenObject = object
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([self.idx], withRowAnimation: .None)
            self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(self.idx, animated: true)
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToNewVC", sender: self)
        }
        else {

        }
    })
}
```

and my network call using Alamofire

```
func getObjectbyId(objectId: String, completion:(Object?) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(Router.getObjectById(objectId: objectId))
        .response { (request, response, data, error) -> Void in
            if response?.statusCode != 200 {
                completion(nil)
            }
            else if let parsedObject = try!NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data as! NSData, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary {
                let object = parsedObject["thing"]
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    completion(object)
                })
            }
    }
}
```

So I made breakpoints, and it actually is going into the completion block the second time and calling it to stop indicator, reload that row, deselect the row, re-enable the tableView userInteraction, and perform the segue. It calls my prepareForSegue as well, but as soon as it finishes, it just sits with the indicator still spinning, and the RAM usage skyrockets up to almost 2GB until the simulator crashes.

I believe it has to do with multi-threading but I can't narrow down the exact issue since I'm putting my important stuff on the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with making the accessoryView of the cell an activityIndicator and then removing it and reloading it all while segueing away. I couldn't figure out how to keep it there and stop the multi-threading issue but I settled for a progress AlertView. If anybody has a solution, I'd love to know how this is fixed.